# Correlation between two vectors?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have two vectors:

```
A_1 = 

      10
      200
      7
      150

A_2 = 
      0.001
      0.450
      0.0007
      0.200
```

I would like to know if there is correlation between these two vectors.

I could subtract to each value the mean of the vector and than do:

```
  A_1' * A_2
```

Are there any better ways?

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"

Comment: You can do a linear regression between the two and check the `r` squared value.

Comment: @ja72: Post it as an answer, with example code please.  Give this question some chance of being saved.

Comment: Also related post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8416968/380384

Comment: @ja72: second to robert, post an answer if you can

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Given:

```
A_1 = [10 200 7 150]';
A_2 = [0.001 0.450 0.007 0.200]';
```

(As others have already pointed out) There are tools to simply compute correlation, most obviously `corr`:

```
corr(A_1, A_2);  %Returns 0.956766573975184  (Requires stats toolbox)
```

You can also use base Matlab's `corrcoef` function, like this:

```
M = corrcoef([A_1 A_2]):  %Returns [1 0.956766573975185; 0.956766573975185 1];
M(2,1);  %Returns 0.956766573975184
```

Which is closely related to the `cov` function:

```
cov([condition(A_1) condition(A_2)]);
```

---

As you almost get to in your original question, you can scale and adjust the vectors yourself if you want, which gives a slightly better understanding of what is going on.  First create a condition function which subtracts the mean, and divides by the standard deviation:

```
condition = @(x) (x-mean(x))./std(x);  %Function to subtract mean AND normalize standard deviation
```

Then the correlation appears to be (A_1 * A_2)/(A_1^2), like this:

```
(condition(A_1)' * condition(A_2)) / sum(condition(A_1).^2);  %Returns 0.956766573975185
```

By symmetry, this should also work

```
(condition(A_1)' * condition(A_2)) / sum(condition(A_2).^2); %Returns 0.956766573975185
```

And it does.

I believe, but don't have the energy to confirm right now, that the same math can be used to compute correlation and cross correlation terms when dealing with multi-dimensiotnal inputs, so long as care is taken when handling the dimensions and orientations of the input arrays.

Comment: -1..1.  Zero means no correlation.  1 max correlation (that means you can make one vector from the other using a positive scale factor).  -1 max negative correlation (that means you can make one vector from the other using a negative scale factor).

Comment: Nothing hard.  As a start, from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence, "correlation cannot exceed 1 in absolute value".

Answer (score 10):

Try `xcorr`, it's a built-in function in MATLAB for cross-correlation:

```
c = xcorr(A_1, A_2);
```

However, note that it requires the [Signal Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/) installed. If not, you can look into the [`corrcoef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) command instead.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Different toolbox... potato, potaato.

Answer (score 7):

For correlations you can just use the corr function (statistics toolbox)

```
corr(A_1(:), A_2(:))
```

Note that you can also just use

```
corr(A_1, A_2)
```

But the linear indexing guarantees that your vectors don't need to be transposed.

Comment: +1: You should mention that this requires the statistics toolbox though :)

Answer (score 6):

To perform a linear regression between two vectors `x` and `y` follow these steps:

```
[p,err] = polyfit(x,y,1);   % First order polynomial
y_fit = polyval(p,x,err);   % Values on a line
y_dif = y - y_fit;          % y value difference (residuals)
SSdif = sum(y_dif.^2);      % Sum square of difference
SStot = (length(y)-1)*var(y);   % Sum square of y taken from variance
rsq = 1-SSdif/SStot;        % Correlation 'r' value. If 1.0 the correlelation is perfect
```

For `x=[10;200;7;150]` and `y=[0.001;0.45;0.0007;0.2]` I get `rsq = 0.9181`.

Reference URL: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/linear-regression.html