# correlation of specific columns (with NaN's)

Tags: matlab

I have two data-sets `D1` (365,3) and `D2` (365,3) with NaN's
I want to find correlation (r, p) of `D1 (column 1) with`D2 (column 1)
I am using

```
good = isnan(D1(:,1))+isnan(D2(:,1));
```

Now I want to use the indexing information of `good==0` to find correlation between first columns of `D1` and `D2`.

Please can someone suggest how i can do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.SSR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to find the correlation between column 1 of D1 and column 1 of D2, excluding the rows with NaN values in either of both columns? Did I understand you correctly?

If yes, then use `good == 0` which will yield a logical vector to select the values of D1 and D2 which you want to be used to compute the correlation:

```
idx = (good == 0)
[R,P] = corrcoef(D1(idx, 1), D2(idx, 1))
```

Also see here for many different ways of computing the correlation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14343567/701049